# Using new keyword in interfaces for methods with different return types to wrap/unwrap data

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, .net-core, dependency-injection

Consider the following interface and class setup setup

```cs
class A {
    public string SomeData {get;set;}
}

class B {
    public string Test{get;set;}
    public int Other{get;set;}
    public decimal Stuff{get;set;}
}

interface Foo {
    A GetA();
    B GetB();
}

interface Bar : Foo {
    new string GetB();
}

class BarImplementer : Bar {
    
    private readonly Foo _foo;
    
    A GetA(){
        // Check cache for existance of A, otherwise use _foo to get A...
    }
    
    string GetB(){
        // Check cache for existance of B, otherwise use _foo to get B...
        return b.Test;
    }
    
    // This is forced upon me by the compiler because otherwise this class "does not implement all methods of interface 'Bar'"
    B Foo.GetB(){}
}
```

Ideally, users of the `BarImplementer` class should not need to deal with the `B` class as they're only interested in the `Test` property of a `B` object.

As you can see from the comments, this won't compile without adding a `B Foo.GetB` implementation with no access modifier. I'm struggling to find examples of the `new` keyword being used to hide methods like this structure in interfaces online.

My question is, what's the most correct way to go about achieving this or equivalent result. Is it better to subclass an implementation of `Foo` in some way to implement the equivalent of `Bar` rather than a `Bar` interface inherit from `Foo` and then implement `Bar` and `Foo` separately.

If it helps, in the reality of this simplified setup (in a Dependency Injection environment), an implementation of `Foo` is used to get data from HTTP calls, and an implementation of `Bar` can cache the result of those calls to avoid making them multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me what all you are trying to accomplish, but I believe your primary issue is the name GetPropertyOfB. Because the name differs from Foo's GetB, it isn't hiding it like you expect. Try changing

```
interface Bar : Foo {
    new string GetPropertyOfB();
}
```

to:

```
interface Bar : Foo {
    new string GetB();
}
```

Comment: Ah woops, typo on my part the name should be the same and it is in the code. I've updated the example to match

Comment: Ah OK, darn. Let me play around with some code and I'll edit if I find a different solution.